# VSCode exstension works while debugging but not once packaged into VSIX

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vsix

I was trying to learn a little bit about building extensions for vscode and I've hit a road block. My extension is only supposed to paste from clipboard with a little extra text depending on the file type. (for quick debugging purposes) The problem is I have this working while debugging but once it is packaged I get a `rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: TextEditor#edit not possible on closed editors`

This makes sense to me but I can't figure out how to keep the activeTextEditor updated nor do I know why it would act different once packaged. I've gotta be missing something simple I'm sure.

```
function activate(context) {
    const dbugText = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.dbug', () => {
        vscode.env.clipboard.readText().then((text) => {
            let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
            if(!editor){
                return;
            }

            var document = editor.document;
            var selection = editor.selection;
            var fileType = document.fileName.split('.')[1];

            console.log(text);

            if (fileType == 'php') {
                text = "dbug(" + text + ");";
            } else if (fileType == 'js') {
                text = "console.log(" + text + ");";
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown file type');
                return;
            }

            vscode.window.showInformationMessage(text);

            editor.edit((editBuilder) => {
                return editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(selection.start.line, selection.start.character), text);
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err.message));
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err.message));
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(dbugText);
}
```